Linux Debian server - very slow disk
My hard disk on server is now very slow, that makes me crazy, I will restart server today night.
hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
Timing cached reads:   22580 MB in  1.95 seconds = 11579.11 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 116 MB in  3.01 seconds =  38.50 MB/sec
on a virtual machine I even got lower speed:
/sbin/hdparm -tT /dev/xvda1
/dev/xvda1:
Timing cached reads:   19376 MB in  1.99 seconds = 9727.48 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads:  50 MB in  3.81 seconds =  13.14 MB/sec
where should I search the issue?

I am going to restart server:
19:04:29 up 1053 days, 21:43,  1 user,  load average: 4.30, 4.60, 4.59

When you say "Hard Disk" are you talking about a HDD, i.e. old school, spinning platters

What is the hardware? What is the system structure (RAIDs, encryption, volume management, file systems)? What is the workload? // 1053 days uptime is very, very bad, it means you hadn't installed security updates for almost three years and this is surely not a reasonable management practice.

I know that, no upgrades is a bad thing... working on it. Restart helped a little... The issue is the xen guests reads from hdd twice slower than the host. I read the issue could be a virtualization type "hvm", but still reading about it. I need to do some experiments to be sure I can switch into other safely. I migraded from older and much smaller server and I didn't notice the issue before. Till my mail system was unresponsive so much.
Disks are a old school hdd, 2 x 3TB merged in RAID 1 programically
